# VHDL shift_left/shift_right stopped working

Tags: vhdl, bit-shift

I had this alu working with the shift left/right function when and the shift amount was being sent in on rd_data2, a 16 bit std_logic_vector.  However I've been forced to change that to a 4 bit std_logic_vector called 'shift' and now it won't shift anymore.

Here's my code.  I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.  Any ideas?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity alu_v2 is
Port ( rd_data1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
       rd_data2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
       alu_mode : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
       result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
            clk :   in  std_logic;
         shift  :   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
         rst    :   in  STD_LOGIC;
       z_flag : out  STD_LOGIC;
       n_flag : out  STD_LOGIC);
end alu_v2;

architecture Behavioral of alu_v2 is

begin

process(rd_data1,rd_data2,alu_mode,rst)

variable    temp :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):=X"0000";
variable    m_temp  :   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

if (rst = '1' ) then
    n_flag <= '0';
    z_flag <= '0';
    result <= X"0000";

    else if (rst = '0') then

        case alu_mode(2 downto 0) is

            when    "000"   =>  NULL;
            when    "001"   =>  temp    := rd_data1 + rd_data2 ;
            when    "010"   =>  temp    :=  rd_data1 - rd_data2 ;
            when    "011"   =>  m_temp  :=  rd_data1 * rd_data2;
                                temp    :=  m_temp(15 downto 0);
            when    "100"   =>  temp    :=  rd_data1 NAND rd_data2 ;
            when    "101"   =>  temp    :=  std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(rd_data1),to_integer(unsigned(shift))));
            when    "110"   =>  temp    :=  std_logic_vector(shift_right((unsigned(rd_data1)),to_integer(unsigned(shift))));
            when    "111"   =>  z_flag  <=  '0';
                                n_flag  <=  '0';

            when    others  =>  NULL;
            end case;

            if (temp    =   X"0000" )   then    z_flag  <=  '1';
                                                    n_flag  <=  '0';
            end if;
            if  (temp(15)   =   '1' )   then    n_flag  <=  '1';
                                                    z_flag  <=  '0';
                else if(temp(15)    =   '0')and(temp > 0)   then    n_flag  <=  '0';
                                                                            z_flag  <=  '0';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;

end if;

result <= temp;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, multiple things are wrong. First of all, even though you have a clock input port, your design is asynchronous. That's probably wrong.

You should either have a synchronous process with an asynchronous reset

```
main_proc: process(rst, clk)
begin
    if rst='1' then
        -- reset stuff
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        -- do stuff
    end if;
end process;
```

Or -preferably- a synchronous process with synchronous reset

```
main_proc: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst='1' then
            -- reset stuff
        else
            -- do stuff
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

This way it will no longer be a problem that signals are missing from the sensitivity list.

Secondly, your flag setting is screwed up. If `alu_mode(2 downto 0)="111"` you first set both flags, but *immediately* overwrite them `if (temp = x"0000" )` or `if (temp(15) = '1' )`. No use in setting them before.

Try to avoid the use of variables anyhow. In this case you can avoid the variables by detecting the zero and n-flag *outside* of the process statement.

```
    signal result_int : unsigned(result'range) := (others => '0');
begin
    -- main_process
    result <= std_logic_vector(result_int);
    z_flag <= '1' when to_integer(result_int) = 0 else '0';
    n_flag <= result_int(result_int'length-1);
```

Thirdly `else if` --> `elsif`... no extra `end if;` needed... And if you type `if rst='1'` then you never have to follow by `elsif rst='0'`: of course `rst='0'` if it's not '1'...

Finally, don't use the `STD_LOGIC_unsigned` package. It's not standardized. Everything you need is in `NUMERIC_STD`.

p.s. if you don't want to worry about signals missing from the sensitivity list, you can use the VHDL-2008 method `process(all)`. This will automatically include all the relevant signals. You will have to compile in VHDL-2008 mode for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have "shift" in your process sensitivity list.